# React Naitve Navigation: How to show a modal from drawer?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

Is there a way to show a modal from drawer in React Native?
There was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63274615/react-native-display-modal-from-react-navigation-drawer) and I changed my code following the answer.

My current code is like this.

`MyRootStackNavigator.tsx`

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();

const MyRootStackNavigator = () => {

  return (
    <Stack.Navigator mode="modal">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Main"
        component={MyDrawerNavigator}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen 
        name="MyModal"
        component={MyModal}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

`MyDrawerNavigation.tsx`

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const MyDrawerNavigator = () => {

  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={MyStackNavigator}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="About this app"
        component={About}
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}
```

But for this code the section to show a modal doesn't appear on drawer. Only `Home` and `About this app` sections appear on drawer.  How can I set the section to show a modal on drawer?

Comment: You can add one more `<Drawer.Screen name="MyModal" component={MyModal} />` inside your `Drawer Navigator` or the second way is to create a `custom Drawer Content`

Comment: @KartikeyVaish When I added it, the modal shows but it shows on a blank screen as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63274615/react-native-display-modal-from-react-navigation-drawer this question said.

Comment: @Ooto do you want to have a button to navigate to About ?

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan No what I want to do is to place a link like `Open Modal` on drawer but when I add it to drawer, the modal shows on a blank screen.

Comment: Ok in that case you need a button inside the drawer which can be don easily, will post an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a CustomDrawerContent which has a modal inside and use a button to open the Modal

```
function CustomDrawerContent(props) {
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
      <Modal
        style={{ flxe: 1, backgroundColor: 'red' }}
        visible={modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => setModalVisible(false)}>
        <Text>Modal Content Here</Text>
        <Button title="Close" onPress={() => setModalVisible(false)} />
      </Modal>
      <DrawerItemList {...props} />
      <DrawerItem
        label="Open Modal"
        onPress={() => {
          setModalVisible(true);
        }}
      />
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}
```

And the DrawerNavigator should be setup like this

```
<Drawer.Navigator
  drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}>
```

You can refer the docs here
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#providing-a-custom-drawercontent

If you want to continue with the code that you have put in the question, you can do like below to navigate to the about screen (Instead of having the modal inside the content)

```
  <DrawerItem
    label="Open Screen"
    onPress={() => {
      props.navigation.navigate('About')
    }}
  />
```

Comment: I will try it soon and let you know!

Comment: Sure, updated the answer with another option you can chose whichever you like

Comment: Btw I don't want to navigate to other screen. I just want to open a modal by clicking a section on drawer. When I add a modal component to `Drawer.Screen`, the modal shows but seems like it navigates to a blank screen. Anyway I will try your solution.

Comment: Ok, then go with the custom content option